# ASCII country at war homework

Tags: c++

I have to make a converter that will take the message  `:mmZ\dxZmx]Zpgy` convert it to its corresponding ASCII number, use this formula

```
if(OriginalChar+Key > 126)
    EncryptedChar = 32 + ((OrgiginalChar + Key) - 127);
else
    EncryptedChar = (OrginalChar + Key);
```

The key in this problem is any number between 1 to 100 so I have to try the formula with every possible key till a message that makes sense is made.

So can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or point me in the right direction

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void converter(char OriginalChar, int Key);

int main()
{
    char OriginalChar[16] = ":mmZ\\dxZmx]Zpgy";
    int Key;

    converter((int)OriginalChar, Key);

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}

void converter()(char OriginalChar, int Key)
{
    char answer;

    for (Key = 0; Key <= 100; Key++)
    {
        if (OriginalChar - Key < 32)
        {
            answer = (((OriginalChar - Key) + 127) - 32);
        }
        else
        {
            answer = (OriginalChar - Key);
        }
        cout << (char)answer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code as it is will not compile. You sure you can compile your code on your system? And looking a bit further, it seems that you write code without knowing what the code exactly means.

Comment: No it won't,I'm getting an error "error: cast from char to int loses precision"

Comment: The expression `(OriginalChar - Key)` promotes `OriginalChar` from `char` to `int`, since `Key` is an `int. You have to explicitly downcast it back to `char` to squelch the warning/error.

Answer (score 1):

One of your problems is that you are casting the entire array of characters to a single integer.  This is very tough thing to do since the integer cannot contain all 16 characters.
See:
    `converter((int)OriginalChar, Key);`

Also, what is the `converter` function supposed to do?
The variable name says you are passing the original character (before encryption), however, you don't have the original character, but the encrypted character.

Why are you passing a copy of the `Key` value but completely overwriting it in the `for` loop?
Did you want to pass it by reference?

**Edit 1:**
Perhaps you want to put the call to `converter` inside a `for` loop:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(OriginalChar); ++i)
{
    converter(OriginalChar[i], Key);
}
```